# Couldn't find Article without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show
Its shows error in this line: `@article = Article.find(params[:id])`
I'm using ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4.0.1 and in console mode its show the save data .

```
  class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path(@article)
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end 
  end
```

/config/routes.rb

```
 BlogN::Application.routes.draw do
 #get "welcome/index"
 resource :articles
 root 'welcome#index'
 end
```

articles/show.html.erb

```
   <p>
   <strong>Title:</strong>
   <%= @article.title %>
   </p>
   <p>
   <strong>Text:</strong>
   <%= @article.text %>
   </p>
```

articles/index.html

## Listing articles

```
    <table>
   <tr>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Text</th>
   </tr>

    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
     <td><%= article.title %></td>
     <td><%= article.text %></td>
   </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Comment: What do the route and url for the `show` action look like?

Comment: Does the ID in the URL map to an existing database record?